# Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome Accounts, Google credential expired everytime

Tags: gnome, 17.04, sync, calendar, google-calendar

I added a google account to my Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 so I have Google Calendar synchronized with Gnome Calendar.
The issue is that after a while Google calendar stops to sync and I can't add new events to it.
If I go to Gnome Online Accounts and I click on my Google Account, it says "credential expired". If i try to remove and re-add it, it will do the same again. I even tried to remove google credential on `seahorse`, but this doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and after some searches I found this thread on Redhat's Bugzilla where someone offers a workaround that worked for me: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1340203#c27

To fix this particular case I had to run `/usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon --replace`, and on that thread they explain how to run this automatically on every login (subsequent logins is where this issue pops up).

Hope this helps anyone running into this issue.

BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.